# Overriding the clone() function in java

Tags: java, clone

I hava a class Stack in which I have a Node declared in it and I need to override the clone() function:

```
public class Stack<T> {
    public class Node<T> {
        T element;
        Node<T> next;

        public Node(T data, Node<T> n) {
            element = data;
            next = n;
        }

        @Override
        public Stack<T> clone() {
            Stack<T> temp = new Stack<T>();
            Node<T> n;
            n = top;
            if(n != null) {
                temp.push(n.element);
                while(n.next!=null) {
                    n = n.next;
                    temp.push(n.element);
                }
            }
            Stack<T> temp2 = new Stack<T>();
            while(!temp.isEmpty()) {
                temp2.push(temp.pop());
            }
            return temp2;
    }
```

I have other functions like push() and pop(), so you can assume they work fine.

The problem is that what im trying to do is to be able to create 2 different stack objects, push some values in to one of them and then clone it to the 2nd one.

with my code this is possible but when I trying pushing values into the stack that was cloned, it automatically pushes values into the 1st stack too.

This is my push

```
public void push(T el) throws MyException {
    Node<T> random = null;
    Node<T> newN = new Node<T>(el, random);

    if(isEmpty()) {
        top=newN;
        newN.next = null;
    } else {
        newN.next = top; 
        Node<T> temp; 
        temp = top;
        top = newN; 
        while(temp.next!=null)
            temp = temp.next; 
        temp.next=null;
    } 
}
```

This is the code for my main function

```
public class Tester
{
  public static void main(String []args)
{
Stack<Integer> test = new Stack<Integer>();
test.push(1);
test.push(3);
System.out.println(test.toString());

Stack<Integer> test2 = new Stack<Integer>();
test2 = test.clone();
test2.push(4);

System.out.println(test2.toString());
System.out.println(test.toString());
 }
 }
```

How can I separate this link?

thank you

Comment: It seems your `clone()` doesn't have a `return` statement. This won't compile.

Comment: Showing the code for `push()` method may help in suggesting answers.

Comment: @Haozhun so sorry, I missed a part of my code...now its complete

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram I have posted my push aswell

Comment: Why do you clone the `Stack` with a method on a `Node`?

Comment: @Dolda2000 Im sorry but I dont really understand your question

Comment: @beckinho - I couldn't find anything wrong in your `push` method apart from the unnecessary `while(temp.next!=null)
            temp = temp.next;

        temp.next=null;` - I don't think it does anything useful. Could you please post your complete code?

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram I dont think the other functions really matter.Im having trouble with the clone(), the other ones work fine.

Comment: @beckinho - From the code you posted, it seems like you have your `clone` method in the class `Node<T>`. is it right?

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram all the classes in java have the clone() method already defined. But im trying to override the the clone() method for Stack class

Answer (score 0):

When you clone, not only you need to create a new Stack object, you also need to create a new Node objects for every element. I'm not sure if that is what you do, since code snippet does not show it. You might just have a typo in your code somewhere. Declare clone() as static temporary and pass Stack as an argument just to see if the code is sound.

Another more convenient options if you are sick of cloning complex data structures - serialize into a byte-array, using plain vanilla Java serialization and then de-serialize into a new Stack. That is called deep cloning.
See [this link](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2007/04/cloning_java_ob.html) for instance